# "Infinite" asynchronous parallel foreach loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await

I have a `List<string>` containing 50K to 100K words

I would like to iterate through it in a *parallel* and *asynchronous* fashion

As an example, I could use

```
while (true)
{
   Parallel.ForEach(words, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 }, ...)
}
```

But problems are:

1. `Parallel.ForEach` isn't *asynchronous*
2. When we arrive at the end of the list, we have to wait for each thread to end before the `while (true)` statement continues
3. Which means that there aren't **always** 100 threads running, which is what I want

How would I be able to achieve this?

Please let me know if this is confusing, or if I'm bad at explaining things.

Comment: You almost certainly do not want 100 threads always to be running...

Comment: 1) Why do you want it to be async?  Considering it's inside an infinite loop it would be dangerous.  Also you **shouldn't** be using `async/await` with `Parallel.xxx` 2) so 3) Maybe, maybe not. `Parallel.xxx` is quite smart with its dynamic thread pool resizing. You might want to consider _TPL DataFlow_ as it supports pipelines; limits and throttles and works well with async. TPLDF caters to both CPU-bound and I/O bound jobs

Comment: @Milney I really do, and perfectly know what I am doing. Anyway, that doesn't contribute to the question

Comment: @MickyD 1) I am using the `HttpClient` API, which is async, I need async lambdas to correctly run in that loop. 2) I know I **shouldn't** be using `async/await` with `Parallel.xxx`. 3) Can you explain what do you mean by "incorrect"? Am I wrong?

Comment: If you *actually* want 100 threads running at same time (which again, you really don't - you must be confused) then you will have to manually use Thread objects. The async implementation in .Net will juggle threads on its own to achieve optimal number, and unless you have 128 core server it won't assign 100 to run at once. Any time you use await a threadpool thread will pick up the continuation, and there will most likely not be 100 threadpool threads

Comment: _" I am using the HttpClient"_ - then you **definately** do not want to spin-up _"100 threads"_.  Spinning up a thread that simply waits for I/O is a waste of a thread. Spinning up a thread that handles only one network link is worse sadly. `Parallel.xxx`is dangerous with `async/await` and you want the latter for its IOCP support.  Best you use TPL DataFlow and `async/await`.  It is magnificent for this sort of thing.  `Parallel.ForEach` is best used for CPU-bound operations which yours isn't it seems

Comment: @MickyD Could you please provide me with an example I could start of?

Comment: @Milney I am doing HTTP request through proxies, and need 100 to concurrently run. Since you're saying I'm wrong (which could be the case), what would be your approach then?

Comment: I told you already - if you actually need to ensure that 100 concurrently run (which again, i'm dubious about - you should usually let .Net manage the optimal number for you, ideally using TPL as others have mentioned) then you need to use the Thread class to manually create 100 threads. Note however as most will be waiting on network IO this will be a massive waste of overhead, and depending on how many cores you have you may not even get 100 scheduled to run at the same time

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y Problem - why do you think you need 100 at the same time?

Comment: @Matt so that's a completely different thing... If you want to get the highest throughput possible, then you DONT want 100 threads sitting waiting on IO, you want to let .NET manage how many threads are the optimal number to get the most requests per second. So you want to use TPL and queue ALL your jobs, and let .Net decide how many threads are best to service that many jobs in the fastest way possible. Deciding that you need 100 running at the same time will make it slower than that

Comment: @Milney Thanks for clarifying. However, there's something I still don't understand after reading your last comment. How, on a 8 core CPU, when using `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100)` followed by a sort of `Parallel.ForEach` loop with `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to 100, am I really able to start 100 HTTP requests at the same time? I can see them all using an HTTP debugger, and my proxy provider also shows me as a live statistic that I am currently using 100 threads.

Comment: Its complicated... You can create and schedule 100 threads, but they won't all be doing something at any given time - many will be waiting for the network request to return, others will be waiting for windows to schedule them. They do however use overhead (memory, cpu for windows scheduler to decide when to next schedule them, etc. etc.). You will find that running 8 threads, each kicking off a request, then starting the next request while waiting for the last to finish, will still result in 100 HTTP calls, but in less absolute time as they won't be wasting as much time

Comment: If you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ and this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl and possibly all of this if you want to know how it works under the hood https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/about-processes-and-threads you may get a better idea.

Comment: It's a common misconception that throwing more threads at I/O _client-side_ will somehow increase throughput _server-side_ at a linear scale.  It's also a common misconception that thowing an excessive number of threads (e.g. _"100"_) at a Windows app on a 8 core machine will lead to the threads magically running continuously _un-interrupted_

Comment: BTW, considering you are on Azure and are after performance, you might want to consider moving to a messaging model (e.g. Azure Message Queue).  Queuing systems offer superior performance compared to RPC-style alternatives, `async` or not.  https://www.amazon.com.au/Enterprise-Service-Bus-David-Chappell/dp/0596006756

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a totally contrived `async` friendly [TPL DataFlow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow) example of how you could achieve what you ask.

1. It's suitable for an async IO workload
2. It's cancellable
3. It limits max parallelism
4. It has bounded capacity so there is always 100 jobs available
5. It's infinite

**Given**

```
private static CancellationTokenSource _cs;
private static CancellationToken _token;
private static ActionBlock<string> _block;

private static async Task MethodAsync(string something)
{
   // Your async workload
}

public static async Task EndlessRunner(string[] someArray)
{
   try
   {
      var index = 0;
      while (!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
         await _block.SendAsync(someArray[index],_token);
         if (++index >= someArray.Length) index = 0;
      }
   }
   catch (OperationCanceledException)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
   }
}
```

**Example**

```
private static async Task Main()
{
   _cs = new CancellationTokenSource();
   _token = _cs.Token;

   _block = new ActionBlock<string>(
      MethodAsync, 
      new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
      {
         EnsureOrdered = false,
         MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100,
         BoundedCapacity = 100,
         CancellationToken = _cs.Token,
         SingleProducerConstrained = true
      });

   var someList = Enumerable
      .Range(0,5000)
      .Select(I => $"something {I}")
      .ToArray();

   Task.Run(() => EndlessRunner(someList));

   Console.ReadKey();

   _cs.Cancel();

   _block.Complete();
   await _block.Completion;

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and I probably never could have done that by myself. I'll make sure to fully understand your code and how it works before using it, and will come back to you if I have any question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Matt dont forget to install the nuget

Comment: So I have a single question. Would doing this work the same? I am sure it would, but just making sure. https://i.imgur.com/d6Ia1Ep.jpg

Comment: @Matt be careful with cancellation, it's effects need to be consistent. If one branch of the code can throw an `OperationCanceledException`, then another branch should not just check the `IsCancellationRequested`, and exit like nothing happened. Consider calling the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method instead.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You are completely right. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hey! Coming back to this, I was wondering if setting `EnsureOrdered` to `true` would slowdown the loop? Thank you (: